# Ambiguous column name on update of new column used in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

#### Scenario

Adding a column to a table and then updating that column

```
alter sometable add example_column_name varchar(255);
update sometable set example_column_name = '';
```

(real update is a bit more complex, but this is a boiled down version we used trying to find the problem)

#### Problem

The update query gives 'Ambiguous column name example_column_name.'

- This works in all databases except one.
- It is only for exactly one specific column name it happens, adding a column with different name and updating that column works
- The column name in question works in other databases, and it already exists in other tables in the same db

#### Question

Does anyone know what's going on, how can we get past this problem?

#### Update

The problem was an indexed view that used the column name of the new column in an already existing query. See comments and accepted answer for details.

Comment: What is the actual column name?

Comment: And whats the database name? And what else is unique about this database? Maybe you have a database trigger which does stuff when you alter the schema?

Comment: No need to do this in two steps anyway. You can do something like `ALTER TABLE sometable ADD example_column_name varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT '' WITH VALUES;` to add the new column and have all existing rows set to empty string

Comment: In the database where it doesn't work are there any DDL triggers? Also unclear if it is the ALTER or the UPDATE getting the error?

Comment: @MartinSmith the actual update that we wish to do is a bit more complex - this update in the question is what we've boiled down to while trying to figure out the problem. No DDL triggers. Updated the question to be more clear about which query is causing the problem.

Comment: What about a trigger on the table itself?

Comment: Can you add a DB<>Fiddle that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Neither of the statements by themselves will generate that error. Either you have SQL you aren't showing us you are running as well, that is generating the error, or you have triggers involved that aren't behaving as you expect (or worse, both). Take the time to produce us a [mre] here; though most likely as and when you do you'll solve the problem (which is why we ask you to make one).

Comment: What is the actual full error message? If this is a trigger the error message will probably have the trigger name

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't have access to any longer error message than "[S0001][209] Ambiguous column name 'example_column_name'"
Though when you asked about triggers I realise there are some views in the database. Could possibly one of these cause the error if the column name is not prefixed properly with table name in their queries? (and i guess a * need to be part of it somewhere too, for that to apply)

Comment: Maybe a view with a SELECT *

Comment: A view won't cause an error when you modify the table, only when you access the view. Unless its a persisted view it might?

Comment: We do have some indexed views, i'll double check them.

Comment: @DaleK Yep that could do it https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8BEa.png

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I found the view that caused the problem. @MartinSmith, would you like to formulate a real answer and i can mark it as confirmed? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can't happen purely from the code shown.

There must be a trigger or indexed view in play. You have ruled out triggers so an example demonstrating the indexed view scenario is below

```
CREATE TABLE T1(X INT, Y INT)
CREATE TABLE T2(X INT, Z INT)

GO

CREATE VIEW V1
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT T1.X,
         T1.Y,
         Z
  FROM   dbo.T1
         JOIN dbo.T2
           ON T1.X = T2.X

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX
  ON V1(X)

GO

ALTER TABLE T1
  ADD Z INT;

GO

UPDATE T1
SET    Z = 0
```

When the view is initially created the only table containing a column `Z` is `T2` so it is not ambiguous. After adding column `Z` to `T1` the view definition becomes ambiguous. The `UPDATE` to the table tries to automatically maintain the view and the error is thrown.

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure V1, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 23]
> Ambiguous column name 'Z'. Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 25 Could
> not use view or function 'V1' because of binding errors.

It is best practice to always use two part naming where your query references more than one table to avoid this type of error.